# Optimize fluent validation code from duplicating to one extension method

Tags: asp.net-web-api, optimization, fluentvalidation

```
public interface IAdditional
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Version { get; set; } 
}

public interface IUser 
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

// dto
public class CreateUser : IUser 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}

// dto
public class UpdateUser : IAdditional, IUser
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Version { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}

internal class UserValidator : AbstractValidator<IUser>
{
    public UserValidator()
    {
        When(u => u is IAdditional, () =>
        {
            RuleFor(u => (u as IAdditional).Id)
                .GreaterThan(0);

            RuleFor(u => (u as IAdditional).Version)
                .NotEmpty();
        });

        RuleFor(u => u.Name).NotEmpty();        
    }
}
```

So, how I could optimize this code part:

```
When(u => u is IAdditional, () =>
{
    RuleFor(u => (u as IAdditional).Id)
        .GreaterThan(0);

    RuleFor(u => (u as IAdditional).Version)
        .NotEmpty();
});
```

This code part i use in every controller. Every controller has f-validator and in every f-validator I use this code lines. It should be great to move it to separate class and reuse it in every f-validator. Tried look to extension method, but I can't understand how it to use make working

Comment: https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/723 Issue solved